# Xamarin IOS Access Incoming Calls

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am just wondering if something is possible - I would like to build an iOS app with Xamarin that accesses incoming calls. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/callkit/)?

Comment: I was reading about it but haven't had a chance to try it out yet. It wasn't clear whether I can get access to all incoming calls it just voip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @ColeXia above for the link to [CallKit](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/callkit/)